# Windows 8 shortcut keys for Modern UI (tiled) Apps

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, modern-ui, windows-store-app

Is there a way to assign shortcut keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (or non-used Windows+key) to Modern UI (Tiled) Apps.
Some of them are useful to be able to bounce in and out of them with a keystroke.

I'm aware how to assign shortcut keys to traditional Windows programs via the `Right Click > Properties > Shortcut key`. But I'm wondering if you can do the same with the Tiled Apps.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a shortcut in your desktop and assign a Hotkey:

For example: This is for People app

**1. Create a new shortcut in your desktop:** using the following format

```
%windir%\explorer.exe [App's URL Protocol name]: <~ ending with colon
```

**App's URL Protocol name?** read about it at the end

[image]

**2. Open its properties dialog and setup the hotkeys you want to use**

[image]

And that's it, now you can launch your Windows 8 applications with that hotkey

**App's URL Protocol**
Some applications have their own URL protocol to open its supported files, something similar to http:// or mailto:

And you will find those names in windows registry : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes

There you will find some of your applications (not all of them), just look for the ones with default value like this one:

```
URL:wlpeople
```

Another hint is that they also have a string value called **URL Protocol**

[image]

Hopefully, you will find your desired-application's URL Protocol name. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) to accomplish this.  There is a hint on how to  do this in Windows 8 in this [forum](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/86511-windows-8-start-screen-clicks/page__hl__metro#entry551019) post on their web site.

Comment: Does Autohotkey supports Modern UI apps now?

Comment: It appears you can handle some events using absolute coordinates.  See this support thread: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/86511-windows-8-start-screen-clicks/page__hl__metro#entry551019

Comment: Have you tried yourself? It will be handy to give an example with your answer. :)

Comment: Follow the link I posted

Comment: Sir, its not me who wants the solution. What if user is not familiar with AHK? In that case it would be handy to give an example in your answer. Sorry if I demand anything more.

Comment: I have not used AHK for this, but understood enough about it to find a possible solution.  I will not copy that here since it is not my AHK script and I couldn't help support it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have not tried it myself but this article on [Create Metro App Shortcuts On Desktop And Pin Metro Apps To Taskbar In Windows 8](http://www.intowindows.com/pin-metro-apps-to-taskbar-in-windows-8/) seems to promise about what you want with a third party tool. From the article

> **MetroApp** Link is a handy tool for computer users running Windows 8 operating system. The tool lets you create shortcuts of Metros-style apps on the desktop and lets you pin apps to the taskbar as well. For instance, you can create a shortcut for the Windows Store app and then pin the same to the taskbar.